# Quick one: What's wrong with this RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this piece of code:

```
_regex = /((?<!placeholder)\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')))/;     
imgTag = imgTag.replaceAll(_regex, ' ');
```

Have also tried this **instead**:

```
imgTag = imgTag.replace( new RegExp( /((?<!placeholder)\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')))/, "gi" ), ' ');
```

But my code never gets passed **this** line:

```
_regex = /((?<!placeholder)\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')))/;
```

Or **this** line:

```
imgTag = imgTag.replace( new RegExp( /((?<!placeholder)\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')))/, "gi" ), ' ');
```

So the problem is in my RegEx, right?

I can't see it, can anyone please shed a light?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Your usage of `RegExp` is completely wrong, but yes, your regular expression is not correct either: `SyntaxError`. JavaScript does not know about lookbehinds `?<!`.

Comment: Could be. This is the first time I'm having more contact with RegExes. I'm using O'Reilly's Regular Expressions Cookbook to pick up some things, but definitely still have a lot to learn about these guys. What would you say is "completely wrong" about that RegEx? And thanks about the lookbehind tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds. You can't write this:

```
(?<!placeholder)
```

Use a lookahead instead:

```
((?!placeholder).{11}|^.{0,10})
```

You'll need to adjust your replacement string too, because this matches extra characters just before the start of what you want to replace.

---

Also this won't work: `var regex = new Regexp(/.../, "gi");`

Write this instead: `var regex = /.../gi;`

Comment: thanks, that was indeed my problem! And about the `new Regexp(/.../)` code, it's because I wanted the `gi` flags, or there's another way to do that with the `replace` function? Thanks again!

Comment: @BeOliveira: If you are using `RegExp`, you have to use a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks again! I'm really enjoying RegEx's, still trying to get a general understanding, though. I used `regexp = /((?!placeholder)\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')))/gi;` instead and it worked. But now I know how to do the same with `RegExp`. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not support look-behind patterns. (That's the `(?< pattern )` part.)